# How to confirm that a set of vectors spans a particular set of vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let's say we have the vectors $(3,2), (4,2), (4,4), (3,3), (3,4), (4,3), (2,4), (2,3)$. Is there any way to show that any vector in the form $(n,m)$ where $n,m \in \{ 2, 3, ..., 9, 10 \}$can be formed by the aforementioned set of vectors?

I realize that this is like solving a system of equations in two variables, but that leads to $8$ variables and $2$ equations... 
I then thought that maybe we could take the determinant of the coefficient matrix, but that clearly doesn't work because the matrix isn't a square one.

Could someone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show that you can form a 2-dimensional vector, then you just need to show that two of the vectors you listed are linearly independent, i.e. show that $x_1 (a_1, a_2) + x_2 (b_1, b_2) = (0,0)$ has a solution only when both $x_1$ and $x_2$ is equal to zero.

Comment: I think you mean "only when both are zero".

Comment: Yes, that's true, will edit

Comment: Thank you for the response, but how does the linear independence condition bring us closer to the desired conclusion? Sorry if it's really obvious... It's not to me...

Comment: @OmicronGamma it follows from a general result that $\mathbb R^n$ is spanned by $n$ linearly independent vectors. So if you want to span any vector in $\mathbb R^2$ you only need two linearly independent vectors of dimension 2.

Comment: I was wondering, how would the additional constraint that the coefficients of the (linearly independent) vectors must be positive or zero affect the problem. As in, to make a vector in the space, a positive coefficient must multiply each vector that constitute the resultant one. Do you have any thoughts on that?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you mean that $x_1$ and $x_2$ in the answer above must be $\geq 0$. In that case, the number of vectors you can obtain are reduced. If you for instance have the vectors $a=(5,0)$ and $b=(0,5)$ it would be impossible to obtain the vector $(-1,-1)$ by forming a linear combination of $a$ and $b$. However, you you could form any of the vectors in your solution set $(n,m)$ where $n,m \in {2,3,....,9,10}$ by using $x_1, x_2 \geq0$

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I meant. Could you prove that we can form any of the vectors $(n,m)$ as you said? I tried it for some small values and it seems that it's true, but is there any way to prove that we can form all of those vectors without testing all 81 pairs of $n$ and $m$?